# How to convert a vue component to html dom

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs3, vite

So I want to convert a vue 3 component to html so that I can calculate an estimate time to read the article.

My articles are in markdown and I am using [vite-plugin-vue-markdown](https://github.com/mdit-vue/vite-plugin-vue-markdown) to convert the markdown to vue components.

During development I can do this to get the text

```js
const dom = new DOMParser().parseFromString(element.default.render().children[0].children, 'text/html')
const innerText = dom.querySelector('body').innerText
```

But after using `vite build` the program doesn't export `.render()`

I also tried this after the build but it gives me this text

- Tried

```js
console.log(new DOMParser().parseFromString(element.default, 'application/xml'))
```

- Output

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <body>
    <parsererror style="display: block; white-space: pre; border: 2px solid #c77; padding: 0 1em 0 1em; margin: 1em; background-color: #fdd; color: black">
      <h3>
        This page contains the following errors:
      </h3>
      <div style="font-family:monospace;font-size:12px">
        error on line 1 at column 1: Document is empty
      </div>
      <h3>
        Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.
      </h3>
    </parsererror>
  </body>
</html>
```

I am doing everything in a `.js` file and not under the `.vue` file

Comment: What about getting the component's root and parsing its `innerHTML`?

Comment: If it's just some text you need, you could use a more specific element's  content.

Comment: Actually, I don't know if you need to parse in that case, as you've already got a "live" DOM.

Comment: I kind of found the answer. I am now using `renderToString` from 'vue/server-renderer'. Not sure though if it the correct approach but it does the job